# Strongly typed references in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, types

I know I can type parameters to functions in PowerShell using:

```
Param (
    [int]$myIntParam
);
```

And I know I can pass by reference like this:

```
Param (
    [ref]$myRefParam
);
```

Is it possible to insist that the reference is to a particular type? For example, is it possible to have it be of type "reference to integer"? Like in C, I would to "pointer to integer" as "int*"... Is there something analogous in PowerShell?

I tried googling around but couldn't find any info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax to specify a "reference-to-type", because `ref` is its own type in Powershell and not a modifier of other types.  However, you can use a script validator to get the same result.

```
function f {
  param(
    [ValidateScript({$_.Value.GetType() -eq [Int32]})]
    [ref] $i
  )
  $i.value += 1
  "New value is $($i.value)"
}

> $x = 5
> f ([ref]$x)
New value is 6
> $x
6

> $y = 'hello'
> f ([ref]$y)
Exception: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'i'.
```